# Infinitely displaying same value Haskell

Tags: haskell, infinite-loop

So i am making a program to display the combined atomic mass of chosen elements. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
start :: Integer -> [Double] -> IO()
start num empty = 
    if num /= 0
        then do
            putStrLn "Term:"
            term <- getLine
            let atom = element term
            putStrLn "Subscript:"
            subscript <- getLine
            let sub = convertToDouble subscript
            let add_element = atom * sub
            let empty = add_element : empty
            putStrLn "Done"
            start (num - 1) empty
        else 
            putStrLn . show $ empty
```

Whenever I run this and pass 0 as num, it works perfectly. But when I pass any other number as an argument, it creates an infinite loop and displays the same value over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

```
let empty = add_element : empty
```

That defines an infinite list of repeated `add_element`. Since `let` is always recursive, use a different name.

```
let notempty = add_element : empty
```